# Sudo git as another user with ssh-agent for key access

Tags: git, ubuntu, sudo

i have ssh-agent setup for the user www-data and the password saved for the private key

from root i need to run "sudo -u www-data git pull" so it doesn't ask for the git private key password. sudo doesn't run the .bashrc script so not sure how to pull this off?

any suggestions?

Comment: How about sourcing the rc file manually? Also, you may have more luck at [unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: apologize for my lack of knowledge but what do you mean rc file manually? i'm not sure how bitmask would help either? thanks

Comment: Eehhh ... first of all, *bitmask* is my user-name, not a suggestion. The other thing is, that you seem to have figured out that the problem results from `sudo` not "running the .bashrc script", so I figured you could fix that by sourcing (i.e. running) that yourself.

Comment: thanks so much! i'm new to this side of things. all i had to do was create a .bash_profile file that sourced .bashrc where my ssh agent script was loading and that worked.

Comment: Great, that's what I get for *commenting* instead of *answering* :) Anyway, this is basically what Jefromi's answer suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want the `-i` option? From `man sudo`:

> `-i [command]`
>
> The `-i` (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified in the passwd(5) entry of the target user as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution. Otherwise, an interactive shell is executed.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work either. it still asks for the password to the key

Comment: it was a combination of using the -i switch with sourcing the .bashrc from .bash_profile (since -i runs .bash_profile or .profile but not .bashrc). Thanks for the help to lead me to the right answer!

Comment: @jadent: Usually the default .profile or .bash_profile sources the bashrc; I didn't know that yours didn't.

Answer (score 4):

I do this, and do an ssh-add as part of my .bash_profile:

```
sudo -u otherusername ssh-agent bash -l
```

Unfortunately, I don't seem to have any history when I use the up-arrow when doing this.  I do, however, when I run the same command minus the sudo part.

By the way, this is what I have in my bash profile to auto-start ssh-agent (only once) and add an RSA key (only once):

```
# Start ssh-agent & add key
if [[ -z $SSH_AGENT_PID ]]; 
then 
    echo Starting ssh-agent automatically...
    ssh-agent bash -l
elif [[ 0 == `ssh-add -l | grep "(RSA)" -c` ]];
then
    echo Adding ssh key automatically...
    # you might have your key in a different location:
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/idents/id_rsa
fi
```