# SSH Login with Password in URL

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, passwords, storage

I have Jenkins cloning the Git repository at

> ssh://user@ip/repo/

and it all works fine, but I need to login with a password, which Jenkins doesn't support. Is there a way to login with the password in the URL? Security is not an issue for me. It should end up being, and I thought it was this at first:

> ssh://user:pass@ip/repo/

but it doesn't work. Thanks!

**Update #1:** The git repo is on the same server.

Comment: Do you need the password for the SSH connection itself, or the password for the private SSH keypair?

Comment: I was hoping to use the actual SSH password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two reason why SSH ask you for a password:

- the public key isn't found on the server, meaning ssh defaults to the account used for the ssh session, asking for its password
- the public key is found, but the private key is password-protected.

The first case means ssh isn't working properly: you should *never* have to enter the password of the account you are using for ssh.
The idea is to be able to authenticate someone even though all ssh connections will use one *unique* account. Entering the password of that unique account defeat the purpose.

The second case should be easy to solve, by [running `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10839376/6309).
That would allow you to *not* enter the password (more than once, when adding the key to the agent).

Comment: Yep, ssh keys were the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Someone could correct me, I don't think this is possible since the password prompt is actually from the SSH server, and not from the SSH application. Looking at my local SSH help page, and there's no way to pass a password into SSH from the command line. This also has some serious security risk with it since the password would be available in plain text.

With that, your best (and more secure) bet would be to do a public/private key pair which wouldn't need a password to setup. Getting this setup with Jenkins and Git can be a little challenging depending on your environment, but it is completely worth it in the end.

Comment: I just spent an hour learning this exact thing -- git credentials was doing nothing for me, and I wanted to bang my head against a wall. But after I set up SSH to work with public/private keys so I didn't have to enter a password (link here: https://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh), it worked immediately. I am currently experiencing a problem solving "high". Thank you.