# Android Studio Git ssh URL with password bug

Tags: android, git, android-studio, authentication, settings

Android Studio 3.1.4 (Sep 2018). Windows. Doesn't accept the password in the URL. I.e.

```
ssh://username:password@my.local.git.server/myrepo/path
```

It is asking for the password for the user `username:password`. Passing an empty one into the dialog window fails to authenticate.

Tried to insert the password directly into the `~/projectFolder/.git/config` - same effect.

**The side problem:** even keeping the "remember passwords" option off it seems to remember the last entered password for a remote URL, so you cannot brute-force the forgotten one until restarting the studio.

What I'm doing wrong or why is that broken?

Comment: ssh URLs don't have passwords. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16273257/7976758

Comment: So, in other words, the reason is that the ssh URL is not supporting the password as it is used to setup the connection on the client side, not on the server side. So for the same reason, the Android Studio can't change it as it's saved not in the regular Studio password store (controlled from the Studio settings), but in the ssh connection configuration file along with keys.

Comment: By the way, entering the right password at the prompt having the `user:password` in the git ssh URL has worked for the Studio.